Conspiracy "documentary" where the intro scene has a submarine in space with a swastika on its side
There was a movie I saw many years ago that was made in a documentary style. I think it was on YouTube or something similar and I specifically remember these details.

Nazi bases in Antarctica.
Reptilian living underground in Antarctica.
The opening scene with a Nazi submarine in space.
Possibly details about the Anunnaki.

It is not the movie Iron Sky. It is in the style of a documentary and I remember watching it alongside of Resonance: Beings of Frequency.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Not Iron Sky, but Iron Sky: The Coming Race has lizardfolk living in a Hollow Earth accessed through Antarctica...

Dark Fleet: The Secret Nazi Space Program and the Battle for the Solar System is a novel that covers a lot of the same topics, and shows a Nazi submarine in space on the cover.

I'm pretty sure the nazis do actually have a moon base. It's why NASA is so reluctant to go back.

There is a quantum submarine in space as well as Nazi moon bases, reptilians, etc in the documentary ABOVE MAJESTIC (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9143304/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_8_nm_0_in_0_q_above%2520ma)

@Valorum of course they have. They even allowed a documentary to film inside. Iron Sky's the name, saw it on YT.

If the work claims to be a documentary, is it on topic here?

@OrganicMarble - Not really.

I’m voting to close this question because a documentary is not fictional, no matter how implausible the views expressed.

@Adamant OP says "in documentary style,"  so this may be a mockumentary (fiction).
